# Calculate differences between array elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a sorted array of n integers, like the following:

```
ary = [3, 5, 6, 9, 14]
```

I need to calculate the difference between each element and the next element in the array.  Using the example above, I would end up with:

```
[2, 1, 3, 5]
```

The beginning array may have 0, 1 or many elements in it, and the numbers I'll be handling will be much larger (I'll be using epoch timestamps).  I've tried the following:

```
times = @messages.map{|m| m.created_at.to_i}
left  = times[1..times.length-1]
right = times[0..times.length-2]
differences = left.zip(right).map { |x| x[0]-x[1]}
```

But my solution above is both not optimal, and not ideal.  Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
ary = [3, 5, 6, 9, 14] #=> [3, 5, 6, 9, 14]
ary.each_cons(2).map { |a,b| b-a } #=> [2, 1, 3, 5]
```

**Edit:**
Replaced `inject` with `map`.

Comment: That is amazingly concise.  Thanks for the awesome answer.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about `each_cons` before. This is a bit shorter version of the same: `ary.each_cons(2).map{|a,b| b-a}`.

Comment: As a side note: it's important to give name to abstractions: [(a, b), (b, c), (c, d), ...] are called "pairwise combinations". And indeed enumerable.each_cons(2).map is the best way to do it in Ruby (thanks to the enumerators all each_xyz methods can now be used "functionally")

Answer (score 7):

Similar but more concise:

```
[3, 5, 6, 9, 14].each_cons(2).collect { |a,b| b-a }
```

Comment: Even more concise if you replace `collect` with `map` :) Note that `each_cons` is not available in 1.8.6, but is available in 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
a.map.with_index{ |v,i| (a[i+1] || 0) - v }[0..-2]
```

*Does not work in Ruby 1.8 where `map` requires a block instead of returning an Enumerator.*